# How to end a python program without it going to the next line of code

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, while-loop

I would like for when a player says no for it to say goodbye then end but instead it goes to Choose a category. Any suggestions?

```
while True:
    choice = input ("Do you want to play?")
    if choice == "yes": 
        print("Great!")
        break # Go to the game
    elif choice == "no":
        print("Goodbye.")
        break # nothing
    else:
        print("Please answer yes or no.")


continent = input("Choose a category: \n"
              "Africa \n"
              "Asia \n"
              "Antarctica \n"
              "Australia \n"
              "Europe \n"
              "North America \n"
              "South America \n")
```

This question is different because its not asking about the loop it is asking how to properly end the program.

Comment: Where's the loop you mentioned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while True:
    choice = input ("Do you want to play?")
    if choice == "yes" 
        print("Great!")
        break # Go to the game
    elif choice == "no" 
        print("Goodbye.")
        break # nothing
    else:
        print("Please answer yes or no.")
```